# Explain how this permutation works

Tags: java

I searched a code for permutation in java:

```
public class MainClass {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      permuteString("", "String");
   } 

   public static void permuteString(String beginningString, String endingString) {
     if (endingString.length() <= 1)
        System.out.println(beginningString + endingString);
     else
        for (int i = 0; i < endingString.length(); i++) {
          try {
             String newString = endingString.substring(0, i) + endingString.substring(i + 1);

             permuteString(beginningString + endingString.charAt(i), newString);
          } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I can't understand it even though I know it was only a basic code. I want someone to explain it to me to make it clearer. Thank you guys

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: This is one of the worst ways to implement a permutation I've seen... Throwing errors as index checking,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can construct a permutation, by *picking* items from a *bag* repeatedly and thus constructing a sequence. For a string, the *bag* is a collection of characters. We can use a `String` to represent this.

If we thus want to construct a *random* permutated string, we first look if the bag is empty. In the above code, the *bag* is the `endingString` and the emptiness check is done with:

```
if (endingString.length() <= 1)
    System.out.println(beginningString + endingString);
```

As you can see the check does not look whether the bag is completely empty: from the moment the string has only one character (one element), it is evidently we will pick that one. So we pick it and print it *after* the sequence we've already constructed.

> *Problem*: a problem with this approach is that if we want to list the permutations of the empty string (there is exactly one: the empty string), one will get errors.

Now we need the iterative case. Remember that `beginningString` stores the sequence we've constructed up till now and `endingString` stores the list of characters we still can pick from. Now a way to pick is to select a valid index `i` in the `endingString`. The character at that index is then picked.

We update the sequence (`beginningString` by simply appending the character that was placed at `i`, thus:

```
beginningString + endingString.charAt(i)
```

In order to update the bag, it means that the bag now contains all the characters before the index, and the ones after the index. This is formalized as:

```
String newString = endingString.substring(0, i) + endingString.substring(i + 1);
```

`newString` is here the new bag. We can then do the recursive call to pick the next item from the bag. So for a given index `i`, in order to pick and call recursively, the code reads:

```
String newString = endingString.substring(0, i) + endingString.substring(i + 1);
permuteString(beginningString + endingString.charAt(i), newString);
```

Now since we wish to enumerate over *all* possible permutations, we loop over all possible indices for `i`. Since we do this recursively as a consequence, we will enumerate all permutations.